# Is there a way to create an Object from a .class-file with missing source code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create an Object of a .class-file that handles multiple 2-d-figures but there is no source code (.java-file) in Java using Eclipse.

The Class has no main methode.

Online I found a way to decompile the .class file. But that isn't a suitable solution because there are legal issues.

Furthermore I tried putting the .class File in the "bin" folder in my workspace where normally .class Files are stored and tried to create an Object of it: `Figuren f = new Figuren();`

This didn't work and I got the following error: `Unresolved compilation problems: Figuren cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to use a 3rd party library, you will want a `JAR` file,  (which you can create yourself, if necessary) not the `.class` file. Other than that, unless you have the source code (either directly or by decompiling), Java cannot use the code...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder => inside that folder, create a folder structure that matches the package structure of the .class file => drop the .class file into the bottom folder => make a zip file out of the new folder you created => change the extension to .jar, => drop the .jar file into your class path (WEB-INF/lib if you're making a web app).